# Renaming an existing entry in the directory gives an error saying "Naming Violation"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap, novell

I'm using Novell in asp.net core 2.2 application to interact with AD. Following functions are working as expected.

- Getting all users, Getting users from specific OU
- Create an User
- Update an User
- Reset password and etc

But when i try to move the entry to new container it gives following exception

- Naming Violation
- ((Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException)e).LdapErrorMessage : "00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090E72, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v4563"

Here is the code block i'm using.

```
var dn = $"CN={user.FirstName} {user.LastName},{this._ldapSettings.ContainerName}"; 
    //dn => CN=arshath shameer,CN=Users,DC=wxyzdev,DC=xyzdev,DC=ca
var newRDn = $"CN={user.FirstName} {user.LastName},OU=DeletedUsers,DC=wxyzdev,DC=xyzdev,DC=ca";
    // newRDn =>  CN=arshath shameer,OU=DeletedUsers,DC=wxyzdev,DC=xyzdev,DC=ca

                using (var ldapConnection = this.GetConnection())
                {
                    //ldapConnection.Delete(dn);
                    ldapConnection.Rename(dn, newRDn, dn, true);
                }
```

I'm following [this](https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/?page=/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/cnet/data/bow8b5m.html) link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues to fix :

- RDN means *relative* DN : the part in the DN that actually makes an
  entry distinguishable from others in the same container, for example : 
  `CN=arshath shameer` in `CN=arshath
  shameer,CN=Users,DC=wxyzdev,DC=xyzdev,DC=ca`. In your case, since you don't want to rename but to move an entry, it doesn't change :

  ```
  var newRDn = $"CN={user.FirstName} {user.LastName}";
  ```
- When moving an entry - contrary to renaming - the RDN stays the same,
  but the parentDN changes :

  ```
  var parentDN = "OU=DeletedUsers,DC=wxyzdev,DC=xyzdev,DC=ca";
  ```

Now let's move the entry :

```
ldapConnection.Rename(dn, newRDN, parentDN, true);
```

You may also need to check whether `{this._ldapSettings.ContainerName}` is replaced with `CN=Users,DC=wxyzdev,DC=xyzdev,DC=ca` to ensure `dn` variable is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this issue. 
Having come across this thread from google, it was not clear to use "CN=arshath shameer".

Please use "**CN=arshath shameer**" instead of **"*CN=arshath
shameer*,CN=Users,DC=wxyzdev,DC=xyzdev,DC=ca"** in the newRDN parameter.

Thanx.
FRS.